# Is there any phrase or idiom for "impossible to find out about something"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

In Persian, when we think it is almost impossible to find out about or discover something, we usually say "even a genie wouldn't find it out!" For example:

"They had stashed the drugs where even a genie wouldn't discover!"

Is there anything like that in English?

Comment: Can you please make an example where this idiom  would be used.

Comment: @user121863 - Even a genie couldn't find out why you think a specific example is necessary when the question explains the concept quite clearly.

Comment: @nnnnnn - I don’t think it is clear enough. Find out what?

Comment: @user121863 - I just added an example.

Comment: What's wrong with the simple word [**undiscoverable**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undiscoverable)? *They had stashed the drugs in a place that was **undiscoverable**.*

Comment: @JasonBassford - Nothing wrong with it, except that I was looking for an idiom!

Comment: @YesMe91 Can you say why? I mean, what is it that an idiom expresses that the simple word doesn't? More specifically, are you looking for something humorous or fantastical? (The simple word doesn't do that.) What kind of subtle meaning or atmosphere do you want the idiom to have? Assuming I could come up with 10 different idioms that mean effectively the same thing as *undiscoverable*, what criteria would I use to narrow them down to the one idiom that's the most appropriate?

Comment: (Incidentally, I find nothing wrong with the expression about a genie in the first place. It might not be an idiom per se, but it's completely understandable and accessible.)

Comment: @JasonBassford - I think in this case an idiom, here the expression about a genie, is more emphatic than a single word.

Comment: So: *They had stashed the drugs so well that **looking for them would be a fruitless endeavour**.* That's not strictly an idiom, but it's a longer expression—and *fruitless endeavour* has the quality of an idiom because it's a common expression. I am not suggesting that as an answer, just trying to narrow down the scope of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The nearest English idiom I can think of is ["God only knows"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/God+only+knows!).

(You might think the word order should be "only God knows", but the idiom has it the other way.)

This idiom gets used in both trivial and serious contexts. The literal meaning is of course that only God would know the answer, but it is also used figuratively to refer to things that might be difficult but not completely impossible to find out.

It can can be used in response to a question, e.g.:

> "Where did they stash the loot?"
> "God only knows."

Or as part of a statement (typically expressing frustration at not knowing):

> "God only knows where they stashed the loot."

Some people shorten it to "God knows". Another equivalent expression is "Heaven knows."

Comment: We too use the expression "God only knows" in Persian. But I was looking for something more similar to the expression about genie. Something with the same negative structure!

Comment: @YesMe91 - This is the nearest English idiom I can think of, actually the only appropriate one that came readily to mind. "God only knows" doesn't have negative wording, but in actual usage the meaning is effectively the same - the obvious implication is that nobody (else) knows how to find out about the thing in question.

Comment: I don't think there is an idiom, *per se* but "They had stashed the drugs where even **Sherlock Holmes would not find them!**" would work.